# Google Site Search + MY search input box

Tags: javascript, html

I am using Google Site Search (the paid one, not Google Custom Search) with a simple search input box…mine, not Google’s.

Here is my very basic input box:

```
<div id="search">
  <form action="http://????????.com" method="GET">
    <input type="text" class="input" name="q" placeholder="Search...">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
  </form>        
</div>
```

The Google Site Search script is something along this order:

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:searchresults-only></gcse:searchresults-only>
```

I am (obviously) not a programmer…otherwise, I’m certain the answer to this would be quite evident. However, can anyone tell me what the HTML requires to pass the search text entered to the script? Directing the “action=” to www.google.com/search working just fine, if I’m wanting an internet-wide search. However, I want to confine the search to the site (hence, Google *Site* Search).

Thanks, in advance, and please advise if I need to clarify any points here.

Comment: Hi. Did Google supply any other code? I haven't used Google Site Search before. But I imagine that setting action to "www.google.com/search" will work because your HTML form will pass whatever's in the input box to Google. That's why you see this in your Google search URL: 'search?q=Stack%20overflow' if you search for 'Stack overflow'. That might be why your form does in internet-wide search. Since that JavaScript imports some more JavaScript, I imagine that's where all the magic happens. Someone feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'd recommend you set up Google Site Search using their documentation, here: https://support.google.com/customsearch/#topic=4513742 and here https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element. Before trying to change it.